# How to manipulate individual character of UITextView in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to manipulate individual character of UITextView like rotating one to the left(90 degrees) and one to the right(90 degrees), and so on.

Anyone has an idea on achieving this?

Comment: Is the character you want to modify in the middle of some other text? Or does your UITextView contain only this one character that you need to rotate? Do you need to rotate only to left and right by 90 degrees, or any other angles?

Comment: In my case, UITextView is created programatically, hence, the contents are dynamic and the modification of each character is dynamic also(anywhere in the text). Yes, the character only rotate left and right by 90 degrees.

Comment: Try using `NSMutableAttributedString` as below - I can also try that later when I get to run it in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to modify individual characters in an `UITextView` is to use `NSMutableAttributedString` by extending it like this:

```
@implementation NSMutableAttributedString (Rotation)

- (void)setRotatedFontWithName:(NSString*)fontName
                         size:(CGFloat)size
                        range:(NSRange)range
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    CTFontRef aFont = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)fontName, size, &transform);
    if (!aFont)
        return;
    [self removeAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName range:range];
    [self addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName value:(id)aFont range:range];
    CFRelease(aFont);
}
```

And then using the `attributedText` property of a `UITextField` to set the rotated font.

What you could also try is creating a custom class that overrides `UITextField`'s default `drawRect:` and draw the normal and rotated text using Core Text methods (see the example in [here](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/core-text), section about rendering text on a curved shape)